# get value from HtmlInputElement and check with user pass

Tags: javascript, typescript, converters, typescript-typings, htmlelements

i want to get this value and check with exist user password:

```
const Users =[{
  userName: 'Hasan1934',
      password: 'Qwx32dksa'
}]
```

and Input value :
`const UserName = document.getElementById("username-field")`
`const Password = document.getElementById("password-field")`
and condition :

```
 for (let index = 0; index < Users.length; index++) {
            let ArrayItem = Users[index];
            if (UserName === ArrayItem.userName && Password === arrayItem.password ) {
                // console.log("your in !!!!!!!!!!!**********");
                break;}}
```

it dosent work for me
`const UserNameHtml = (document.getElementById("username-field") as HTMLInputElement).value`

Comment: Try using `querySelector`, `getElementById` is known to be tricky when used in one-liners and non DOM elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const Users =[{
   userName: 'Hasan1934',
   password: 'Qwx32dksa'
}]

function isUserExist() {
   const UserName = document.getElementById("username-field");
   const Password = document.getElementById("password-field");
   return !!Users.find(u=>u.userName===UserName.value &&u.password===Password.value);
}
isUserExist();
```